# Laravel set cookie name include dot (.)

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to send a cookie whose name contains two dots.
this is my code

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Cookie'    => '.cookie.withdots=test-value'
])->get('http://example.com');
```

now when I send this request to my system on another route and print the cookies dots(.) has transformed to underscores(_)

```
array:1 [
  "_cookie_withdots" => "test-value"
]
```

I need them to stay as dots(.)
what can i do guys?

Comment: I deleted my answer, I postet some wrong information there. Check in the network tab with the browser: The dots are set in `Set-Cookie` and they are returned in `Cookie` header, but PHP replaces dots in incoming variables by `_` automatically.

Comment: @DanielW. a cookie name is not a PHP variable though. Array indices have no problem containing a dot.

Comment: You are sending this to your own system? Just get rid of the dots then.

Comment: @miken32 When PHP receives a value via HTTP it automatically turns dots into underscores. Same for Cookie headers, same for GET variables.

Answer (score -1):

There is a dedicated method to set the cookies:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses

```
return response('Hello World')->cookie(
 '.cookie.withdots', 'test-value', 10
);
```

Comment: They are not sending a response, they are making an HTTP request to a remote server.

Comment: how are they making an HTTP request to a remote server by using `response()` method?

Comment: The only one using `response()` here is you. The question is about `Http::get()`